# How to run Xorg server on integrated GPU?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, cuda

I have 2 Nvidia GTX1080 dedicated GPUs and 1 Intel integrated GPU installed on my machine. I want to use nvidia GPUs only for scientific computations. Even though I plugged monitors to main board, Xorg server uses one of the nvidia GPUs and allocate nearly 700 MB of memory.

How can I force Xorg server to only use Intel GPU?

`lspci | grep 'VGA'` output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5912 (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b80 (rev a1)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b80 (rev a1)
```

`nvidia-smi` output:

```
Tue Jan  2 15:24:18 2018       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.98                 Driver Version: 384.98                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 32%   59C    P5    16W / 180W |   1322MiB /  8114MiB |      4%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 33%   60C    P2    56W / 180W |   7858MiB /  8114MiB |     27%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     12818      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           638MiB |
|    0     13476      G   compiz                                       278MiB |
|    0     14230      G   ...-token=A9CF4CD99B5947DB32E9E4B117997A68   404MiB |
|    1     25764      C   python                                      7847MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change PRIME profiles to Intel(Power Saving Mode) in NVIDIA X Server Settings
2. Log out / Log in
3. add
   `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:/usr/lib/nvidia-xxx` 
   (mine is nvidia-384) to ~/.bashrc file
4. run nvidia-smi

If it doesn't work make sure Secure Boot is disabled in UEFI settings.